# Trouble parsing JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse some text files containing JSON objects in Python using the json.load() method. It's working for one set of them, but for this one it will not:

```
{
"mapinfolist":{
  "mapinfo":[
  {"sku":"00028-0059","price":"38.35","percent":"50","basepercent":"50","exact":0,"match":0,"roundup":0}
  ,{"sku":"77826-7230","price":"4.18","percent":"60","basepercent":"60","exact":1,"match":0,"roundup":0}
  ,{"sku":"77827-1310","price":"2.36","percent":"60","basepercent":"60","exact":1,"match":0,"roundup":0}
  ,{"sku":"77827-2020","price":"2.36","percent":"60","basepercent":"60","exact":1,"match":0,"roundup":0}
  ,{"sku":"77827-3360","price":"2.36","percent":"60","basepercent":"60","exact":1,"match":0,"roundup":0}
  ,{"sku":"77827-4060","price":"2.36","percent":"60","basepercent":"60","exact":1,"match":0,"roundup":0}
  ,{"sku":"77827-4510","price":"2.36","percent":"60","basepercent":"60","exact":1,"match":0,"roundup":0}
  ,{"sku":"77827-7230","price":"2.36","percent":"60","basepercent":"60","exact":1,"match":0,"roundup":0}
  ],
  "count":2
}
}
```

It is in a file called 'map.txt' - I open it using open('map.txt') and then call json.load(). When I run my test program (test.py), the following error trace is generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 23, in main
    map_list = json.load(f1) 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The JSON object is valid - when I put it into https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ it is parsed and displayed correctly, so I am having trouble identifying what could be stopping it from working when I try to do it in Python. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Here's my code.

```
import json
def main():

with open('map.txt') as f1:
    map_list = json.load(f1)
```

Trying `map_list = json.loads(f1.read())` also does not work and gives me an almost identical error trace.

EDIT - RESOLVED:

I just copied and pasted FROM map.txt into a new TextEdit file map2.txt and used the new file instead, and it works now. I copied directly from the old file and made no changes - the only difference is that it is a different file. I can't make heads or tails of why that would be - any ideas? I would like to understand what may have happened so I can avoid the problem in the future.

Comment: @John it has been added!

Comment: If I copy your JSON content into a file and load it with `json.load(file('blah.txt'))` in Python 2.7 it works fine. If I copy it into http://ideone.com and use Python 3 and  `json.loads(""" blah blah """)` it works. Weird. I have to guess it's either referencing the wrong file (typo in the name) or the file was saved in a weird editor / encoding that makes it be interpreted differently?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I saved it in TextEdit and made sure it was plain text. The filename is definitely correct as well. :(

Comment: By the trace there is definitely more code than just that @shinytinsmile and it may be cause by other lines of code and not necessarily in this chunk you gave us. Because your code works that you gave us

Comment: @heinst The other lines of code are commented out, so I did not include them here.

Comment: It's a point.  I notice in the error it says `MAP_list = json.load(f2) ` and in your code sample it's called `f1` - any chance you're opening the right file name but then passing json.load a different file variable?

Comment: Thats what Im saying @TessellatingHeckler the trace isnt matching up with what the code that was given

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Apologies, I've been changing things around a lot trying to debug and copied the wrong trace. They are currently both 'f1' and I am getting the same error. My post has been modified to reflect this.

Comment: Okay, I just copied and pasted FROM map.txt into a new textedit file map2.txt and used the new file instead, and it works now. I can't make heads or tails of why that would be - any ideas? I would like to understand what may have happened so I can avoid the problem in the future.

Comment: From the error, saying line 1 position 1 char 0 I'm thinking there's a null character `\x00` as the first character in the file `map.txt`, and now there isn't in map2.txt, but I haven't been able to prove whether that will give the same error. Maybe try in a Python shell some things like: `a = file('map.txt').read(10)`; `b = file('map2.txt').read(10)`; `print(a)`; `print(b)`; `print(a == b)`, and see what the first 10 characters of each file are showing up as, and if they have changed.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks! I tried this and no matter how many characters I try to read on 'map.txt', when I print, I get a blank line - however I do get the first 10 correctly when I read 'map2.txt'. Doing `b = open('map.txt').read()`;`print(b)` also gives me just a blank line. Why would this entire file appear to be null when I can clearly read it?

Comment: Interesting ... I have no clear idea what's going on with it, except that it still sounds like file encoding and automatic decoding going wrong, and TextEdit can read the encoding and is hiding what's really happening. You could try looking at the files in a hex editor - something which won't interpret the contents as text characters, and will show you the raw byte stream. I guess you're on a Mac, maybe http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/   and see how map.txt starts vs map2.txt

Comment: Possibly the problem is [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Using hexdump -n10 to see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following solution work for you?

```
import json
f = open("map.txt")
map = json.loads(f.read())
```

[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: It was probably an unusual white space ('\r\n') or ('\t') perhaps. Often times opening a file in emacs can highlight these unusual white spaces that can get injected by some windows applications.

Answer (score -2):

maybe try to read all the file to string and then use json.loads

```
         def yourfunc():
             file = open('map.txt')
             json_string = file.read()
             map = json.loads(json_string)
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Some sample code would be more helpful